# Refresh Activity inside Tab Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-tabactivity

I created some activity(say A, B and C) under TabActivity and use `m_tabHost.setCurrentTab(n);` to launch appropriate Activity. Here I activity(say A) get launch as per behaviour on-click of define tab(say TAB A). Now how can reload same activity on click of same tab. How can get access of same tab to reload same open activity.

Any one have suggestion/idea?

Comment: You want that if you click on Tab A (while it is open already), the activity in it would refresh?

Comment: yes...exactly same...and reason to do it..I am opening different page inside that activity...based on some other conditions..any suggestion?

Comment: Whats your motive? Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: I am using PageViewer inside Activity...n depend on condition I set page inside activity..now if user click on Tab again then it should reset view pager to first position.